# Copy a folder to Azure web app without FTP

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have an application which is using internal file storage (folder) I can't include this folder in the project since the build is failing. I can deploy this build package which is a zip file using Azure Deploy task in the release pipeline but how can I copy that folder to the WebApp?

> I don't have access to the FTP due to company policy

- I can copy that folder to storage blob but then how can copy it to web app again?

Comment: Not get your latest information, are the workarounds below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: If one of the answers works for you, make sure to accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

In the **Azure Portal**, locate your Web App and click on the **Advanced Tools** menu.  Click **Go** to launch the Kudu console. Select **CMD** from the **Debug Console** menu.  You'll be presented with a graphical file explorer and a command line prompt.  Simply drag and drop your local folder in the top portion.

Comment: for more info, you can visit https://www.gslab.com/blogs/kudu-azure-web-app

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Kudu REST API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/REST-API)

> `PUT /api/zip/{path}/`
>
> Upload a zip file which gets expanded into the specified folder. Existing files are not deleted
>   unless they need to be overwritten by files in the zip. The path can be nested (e.g. `folder1/folder2`), and needs to exist.